# Fancybox Forms in Rails don't work properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, tabs, fancybox

I know I'm a newbie in Rails but this is the second day I'm going to waste because of this. Could anybody help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?

I want my user to register from the home page. Click on "Register" button and a fancybox appears with two tabs inside the box, because they can choose between two different forms of registration. Everything is set right, because the fancybox appears but there an error message inside.

In the **home page**:

```
<ul class='nav pull-right'>
   <%= render 'devise/menu/registration_items' %>
</ul>
```

In **registration_items**:

```
<% if society_signed_in? %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to('Edit registration', edit_society_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to('Register', regist_setup_path)  %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Then in setup:

```
<div class="fancybox">
  <h2>Sign up</h2>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#society">Society</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#collaborator">Collaborator</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="society">  
      <%= render :partial => 'societies/form' %>  
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="collaborator">Collaborator
      <%= render :partial => 'collaborators/form' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The two render :partial just show the forms correctly. 
Then Jquery in the **application.js** after all the  //= require blablabla.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

I tried to set @society = Society.new and @collaborator = Collaborator.new in my application controller but it still doesn't work

EDIT: 
What happen is me clicking on the register button, the setup page appears and when I click on each tab, the box appears with: 
 The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later. error message

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: My guess is that you need to pass the ivars to the partials via a locals hash.

Comment: what version of fancybox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is rails related -- Fancybox, and other javascript plugins like this, attach to a link element, so that when they are clicked, it will load up the content based on the href of the link.

your jquery call should be (in window load)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

So I think you'd want this:

```
<%= link_to('Register', "#popup-signup", :class=>"fancybox")  %>
```

Then the content in the popup:

```
<div id="#popup-signup">
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  ..more stuff here
```

Comment: I guess you meant `$("a.fancybox").fancybox();` that binds that (link) selector to fancybox.

Comment: That actually worked. Nesting code puzzled me. I just added the :class attribute in link_to method and it worked.
Thanks